# Itext fit Image to cell

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I tried to fit an image to table cell. However, when I print my document, there is a small sit image on top of other image as show in picture. What problem am I facing?

[image: Screenshot]

```
public class PrintableLabel {
private static Font arial_12 = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 12, Font.BOLD);
private static Font arial_11 = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 11, Font.BOLD);
private static Font arial_10 = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 10, Font.BOLD);
private static Font arial_9 = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 9);
private static Font arial_9_bold = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 9, Font.BOLD);

public static ByteArrayOutputStream generateOFSLabel(List<PrintableLabelConfig> configList) throws IOException{

    float topBottommagin = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.inchesToPoints(1.0f);
float leftRightmagin = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.inchesToPoints(0.25f);

float labelHeight = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.inchesToPoints(6.0f);

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, leftRightmagin, leftRightmagin, topBottommagin, topBottommagin);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
      document.open();
      // Main table
      PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
      table.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);
      table.getDefaultCell().setBorderWidth(0);

      PdfPCell cell_1 = new PdfPCell();//Table one the RIGHT
      cell_1.setPadding(20);
      cell_1.setFixedHeight(labelHeight);
      cell_1.setBorderWidth(0);

      PdfPCell cell_2 = new PdfPCell();//Table two the LEFT
      cell_2.setPadding(20);
      cell_2.setFixedHeight(labelHeight);
      cell_2.setBorderWidth(0);

      PdfPCell cell_3 = new PdfPCell();//Table three the BOTTOM RIGHT
      cell_3.setPadding(20);
      cell_3.setFixedHeight(labelHeight);
      cell_3.setBorderWidth(0);

      PdfPCell cell_4 = new PdfPCell();//Table four the BOTTOM LEFT
      cell_4.setPadding(20);
      cell_4.setFixedHeight(labelHeight);
      cell_4.setBorderWidth(0);

      PrintableLabelConfig config_1 = configList.get(0);
      PrintableLabelConfig config_2 = configList.get(1);
      PrintableLabelConfig config_3 = configList.get(2);
      PrintableLabelConfig config_4 = configList.get(3);

      cell_1.addElement(tableFor(config_1));
      cell_2.addElement(tableFor(config_2));

      cell_3.addElement(tableFor(config_3));
      cell_4.addElement(tableFor(config_4));

      table.addCell(cell_1);
      table.addCell(cell_2);

      table.addCell(cell_3);
      table.addCell(cell_4);

      document.add(table);
      document.close();
  } catch (DocumentException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
    return baos;
}

private static Image logoElement() {
    String path = "/xampp/tomcat/webapps/ocsLabel/jsp/ofs/logo/ofs_logo.png";
    //Eclipse\Workspace\ocsLabel\WebContent\jsp\ofs\logo
    //String path = "/Eclipse/Workspace/ocsLabel/WebContent/jsp/ofs/logo/ofs_logo.png";
    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = Image.getInstance(path);
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

private static final Image img = logoElement();
private static PdfPTable tableFor(PrintableLabelConfig tableConfig){
    String partNumber = "";
    String partNumberDesc = "";
    String serialNumber = "";
    Set<ReportStub> lossDataInfoSet = null;
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
    String datePrint = sdf.format(todayDate);
    String length = "";
    String unit = "";

    if(tableConfig !=null){
        partNumber = tableConfig.getOfs_PartNumber();
        partNumberDesc = tableConfig.getOfs_Description();
        serialNumber = tableConfig.getOfs_SerialNumber();
        lossDataInfoSet = tableConfig.getLossDataInfo();
        length = tableConfig.getLength();
        unit = tableConfig.getUnit();
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setWidthPercentage(100f);

    insertCell(table, img, 0, 3, 2);

    /*(PdfPTable table, String text, int align, int colspan, Font font, int padding, float grayFill)*/
    insertCell(table, "Part Number: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1, arial_12, 0, 0.0f);// This is Part Numbertitile
    insertCell(table, partNumber, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, arial_10, 0, 0.0f); // This is Part Number info

    insertCell(table, "Description: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 0, arial_12, 0, 0.0f); // This is Description titile
    insertCell(table, partNumberDesc, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, arial_9_bold, 0, 0.0f); // This is Description info

    insertCell(table, "Serial #: ", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 0, arial_12, 0, 0.0f); // This is Serial # titile
    insertCell(table, serialNumber, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 2, arial_9_bold, 0, 0.0f); // This is Serial # info

    insertCell(table, "Loss Data", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, arial_11, 0, 0.85f); // This is Loss Data
    insertCell(table, "Insertion Loss dB", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, arial_11, 0, 0.85f); // This is Loss Data
    insertCell(table, "Return Loss dB", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, arial_11, 0, 0.85f); // This is Loss Data

    if(lossDataInfoSet !=null && lossDataInfoSet.size() >= 1){
        for(ReportStub report: tableConfig.getLossDataInfo()){
            insertCell(table, "LC-"+report.getFib_Sequence_Nr()+"    A/B", Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0, arial_10, 0, 0.0f);
            insertCell(table, MathUtil.precision(2, report.getFim_IL_End_A())+" / "+MathUtil.precision(2, report.getFim_IL_End_B()), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0, arial_10, 0, 0.0f);
            insertCell(table, MathUtil.precision(2, report.getFim_Reflectance_End_A())+" / "+MathUtil.precision(2, report.getFim_Reflectance_End_B()), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0, arial_10, 0, 0.0f);
        }
    }else{
        insertCell(table, "LC-    A/B", Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0, arial_11, 0, 0.0f);
        insertCell(table, "/", Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0, arial_11, 0, 0.0f);
        insertCell(table, "/", Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, 0, arial_11, 0, 0.0f);
    }

    insertCell(table, "Date Of MFG", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, arial_9, 0, 0.85f); // This is "Date Of MFG"
    insertCell(table, length+" "+unit, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, arial_10, 0, 0.85f);
    insertCell(table, datePrint, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, 0, arial_9, 0, 0.85f);

    return table;
}

private static void insertCell(PdfPTable table, Image img, int align, int colspan, int padding){

    //scale image
    img.scalePercent(90);

    //create a new cell with the specified Image
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img);
    //set the cell alignment
    if(align != 0){
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }
    //set the cell column span in case you want to merge two or more cells
    if(colspan != 0){
        cell.setColspan(colspan);
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }
    //set the cell padding
    if(padding != 0){
        cell.setPadding(padding);
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }

    //add the call to the table
    table.addCell(cell);
}

private static void insertCell(PdfPTable table, String text, int align, int colspan, Font font, int padding, float grayFill){
    //create a new cell with the specified Text and Font
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text.trim(), font));
    //set the cell alignment
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(align);
    //set the cell column span in case you want to merge two or more cells
    if(colspan != 0){
        cell.setColspan(colspan);
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }
    //set the cell padding
    if(padding != 0){
        cell.setPadding(padding);
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }
    //set gray fill
    if(grayFill != 0.0){
        cell.setGrayFill(grayFill);
    }else{
        //Do nothing
    }
    //add the call to the table
    table.addCell(cell);
} 
}//End public class PrintableLabel
```

Comment: That images doesn't get added "automagically." That image is there because you're doing something wrong. We can't tell you which problem you're facing because you're not sharing any of your code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my question

Comment: I tried to change the image in "bottom left table" to different image. Then, the "bottom right table" get the same problem.